# How to use a COM VARIANT in Rust winapi programming?

Tags: c++, winapi, rust

I'm trying to convert the [C++ COM code](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/aa382113(v=vs.71)) for `TaskScheduler` to Rust and am stuck with the `VARIANT` argument of `ITaskService::Connect`:

```rust
extern crate winapi;
use winapi::{
    ctypes::c_void,
    shared::{
        guiddef::{GUID, REFCLSID, REFIID},
        ntdef::{HRESULT, NULL},
        rpcdce::{RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE},
        winerror::FAILED,
        wtypes::VARENUM,
        wtypesbase::CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    },
    um::{
        combaseapi::{CoCreateInstance, CoInitializeEx, CoInitializeSecurity, CoUninitialize},
        oaidl,
        objbase::COINIT_MULTITHREADED,
        taskschd::{ITaskService, TaskScheduler},
    },
    Class, Interface,
}; // 0.3.7

fn main() {
    //  Create an instance of the Task Service.
    let mut p_service: *mut ITaskService = unsafe { std::mem::zeroed() };

    let hr = unsafe {
        CoCreateInstance(
            &TaskScheduler::uuidof(),
            std::ptr::null_mut(),
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            &ITaskService::uuidof(),
            &mut p_service as *mut *mut ITaskService as *mut *mut c_void,
        )
    };

    // [...]
    // //  Connect to the task service.
    // let hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(),
    //     _variant_t(), _variant_t());

    let hr = unsafe {
        (&mut *p_service).Connect(
            oaidl::VARIANT { /* VT_EMPTY HERE */ },
            oaidl::VARIANT { /* VT_EMPTY HERE */ },
            oaidl::VARIANT { /* VT_EMPTY HERE */ },
            oaidl::VARIANT { /* VT_EMPTY HERE */ },
        )
    };
}
```

[The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-variant-t?view=vs-2019#remarks) say:

> **`_variant_t( )`** Constructs an empty `_variant_t` object, `VT_EMPTY`.

I found no mention on how to use the variant as stated in the README:

> Use `std::mem::zeroed()` to create an instance of the union, and then assign the value you want using one of the variant methods.

When checking the docs for "variant", there's no `_variant_t` fn on the list, so not sure what it is called in Rust

Errors

```
field `0` of struct `winapi::um::oaidl::VARIANT_n1` is private

field `0` is private
```

for

```rust
  oaidl::VARIANT {
    n1: oaidl::VARIANT_n1 {
      0: [0, 0, 0]
    }
  }
```

Comment: `_variant_t` is a c++ class so I suppose you must bind something to one of its constructor. Bindgen should be able to do it for you. How do you bind all this API so far ? Your question lack of detail.

Comment: `_variant_t` is just a C++ helper class that wraps a COM `VARIANT`, it automates memory management and reference counting for `VARIANT` values.  `_variant_t` doesn't exist in other languages, like Rust, so you will have to construct a `VARIANT` manually and populate it as needed.

Comment: A COM [`VARIANT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-tagvariant) is a tagged union, have a look at [How Rust Implements Tagged Unions](http://patshaughnessy.net/2018/3/15/how-rust-implements-tagged-unions) and [A quick tour of Rust’s Type System Part 1: Sum Types (a.k.a. Tagged Unions)](https://tonyarcieri.com/a-quick-tour-of-rusts-type-system-part-1-sum-types-a-k-a-tagged-unions)

Comment: to be completely clear: I'm stuck and have not made any progress, there's no reproducible example because of this, and winapi::um must have `winuser` enabled in Cargo features. 
`VARIANT_n1` is private and can't be used when using `VARIANT { n1: /*...*/ }`.

Comment: @pocesar did you ever find a solution? Im trying to create a scheduled task in windows with rust as well but no luck so far. Can you help?

Comment: @scrubjay55 if you're still stuck check out my new reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing unions is explained in [`winapi`'s README](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/blob/46aa861d606b21ded202a606b1351214ea899fa3/README.md#how-do-i-create-an-instance-of-a-union):

> ### How do I create an instance of a union?
>
> Use `std::mem::zeroed()` to create an instance of the union, and then
>   assign the value you want using one of the variant methods.

For instance, for [`VARIANT_n1`](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.7/winapi/um/oaidl/struct.VARIANT_n1.html), the methods are `n2`, `n2_mut`, `decVal` and `decVal_mut`. You will naturally need to use a `_mut` method to assign a value.

Note that, starting with winapi 0.3.7, you can also use `Default::default()` to obtain a zeroed union instead of using the unsafe `std::mem::zeroed()`. You need to enable the `impl-default` feature on the `winapi` crate for the `Default` trait to be implemented.

Comment: `the trait 'std::default::Default' is not implemented for '*mut winapi::um::taskschd::ITaskService'` and `the trait 'std::default::Default' is not implemented for 'winapi::um::oaidl::VARIANT_n1'`. while searching for those methods, it seems that they are defined in another external crate, called `oaidl` (that makes working with those variants less painful)

Comment: But `_variant_t` is not an union. It's class or I miss something

Comment: @pocesar [Default](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.7/winapi/um/oaidl/struct.VARIANT_n1.html#impl-Default) is implemented for VARIANT_N1.

Comment: @pocesar Make sure you're using winapi 0.3.7 or later. The `Default` implementations were added in 0.3.7. Use `cargo update` to update your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a variant with

```rust
use winapi::um::oaidl::VARIANT;

fn doStuff() {
  unsafe {
    let mut variant: VARIANT = std::mem::zeroed();
    // set values here
  }
}
```

`variant.n1.n2().vt` contains the type (e.g. winapi::shared::wtypes::VT_BOOL or winapi::shared::wtypes::VT_EMPTY, [msdn describes the possible values here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ne-wtypes-varenum)), the `variant.n1.n2().n3` union contains the value.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time but I am still unable to instantiate a variant with a bstr value in order to pass as an userId to RegisterTaskDefinition()