# How to show progress in taskbar button?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, taskbar

Please, can someone post an example how to show the progress in a taskbar button on Windows?

I've seen that the winapi crate seems to have support for this:

> `winapi::um::shobjidl_core::ITaskbarList`
>
> `winapi::um::shobjidl_core::ITaskbarList4`

But I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: `ITaskbarList4` is a COM interface exposed by Windows. An example of using a COM interface (although not this specific one) is available in [How to use a COM VARIANT in Rust winapi programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56571553/62576), which may be enough to get you started.

Comment: You can probably use the [com crate](https://github.com/microsoft/com-rs) to make it easy to instantiate and manage COM objects. The GitHub repository also links to other [existing crates](https://github.com/microsoft/com-rs#existing-crates) that may be better suited. Unrelated to the concrete solution, I think you only need the `ITaskbarList3` interface to implement taskbar progress indicators, not `ITaskbarList4` (although that doesn't much change the implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [WinSafe](https://crates.io/crates/winsafe) crate things are a lot cleaner (and easier):

```rust
use winsafe::{self as w, co, shell};

let hwnd: HWND; // handle to your window, initialized somewhere

// Create the COM object.
let itbl: shell::ITaskbarList4 = w::CoCreateInstance(
    &shell::clsid::TaskbarList,
    None,
    co::CLSCTX::INPROC_SERVER,
).unwrap();

// Set the progress to 50%.
itbl.SetProgressValue(hwnd, 50, 100)
    .unwrap();

// Set the color to yellow.
itbl.SetProgressState(hwnd, shell::co::TBPF::PAUSED)
    .unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found out how to do it:
- Use winapi-tlb-bindgen-master crate to create Rust code from the tlb file (TaskBarLib.tlb).
- Modify this Rust file until it compiles without error (e.g. I had to insert the macro code for UNION from the winapi Rust crate, because this macro is not exported).

Here is the code of the TaskBarLib.rs file:

```
#![allow(non_camel_case_types, non_snake_case, unused)]

use winapi::ctypes::c_void;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::UINT;
use winapi::shared::winerror::HRESULT;
use winapi::shared::wtypes::{BSTR, VARIANT_BOOL};
use winapi::um::oaidl::{IDispatch, IDispatchVtbl, LPDISPATCH, VARIANT};
use winapi::um::unknwnbase::LPUNKNOWN;
use winapi::um::winnt::LPCWSTR;
use winapi::{ENUM, RIDL, STRUCT};

macro_rules! UNION {
    ($(#[$attrs:meta])* union $name:ident {
        [$stype:ty; $ssize:expr],
        $($variant:ident $variant_mut:ident: $ftype:ty,)+
    }) => (
        #[repr(C)] $(#[$attrs])*
        pub struct $name([$stype; $ssize]);
        impl Copy for $name {}
        impl Clone for $name {
            #[inline]
            fn clone(&self) -> $name { *self }
        }
        #[cfg(feature = "impl-default")]
        impl Default for $name {
            #[inline]
            fn default() -> $name { unsafe { $crate::_core::mem::zeroed() } }
        }
        impl $name {$(
            #[inline]
            pub unsafe fn $variant(&self) -> &$ftype {
                &*(self as *const _ as *const $ftype)
            }
            #[inline]
            pub unsafe fn $variant_mut(&mut self) -> &mut $ftype {
                &mut *(self as *mut _ as *mut $ftype)
            }
        )+}
    );
    ($(#[$attrs:meta])* union $name:ident {
        [$stype32:ty; $ssize32:expr] [$stype64:ty; $ssize64:expr],
        $($variant:ident $variant_mut:ident: $ftype:ty,)+
    }) => (
        #[repr(C)] $(#[$attrs])* #[cfg(target_pointer_width = "32")]
        pub struct $name([$stype32; $ssize32]);
        #[repr(C)] $(#[$attrs])* #[cfg(target_pointer_width = "64")]
        pub struct $name([$stype64; $ssize64]);
        impl Copy for $name {}
        impl Clone for $name {
            #[inline]
            fn clone(&self) -> $name { *self }
        }
        #[cfg(feature = "impl-default")]
        impl Default for $name {
            #[inline]
            fn default() -> $name { unsafe { $crate::_core::mem::zeroed() } }
        }
        impl $name {$(
            #[inline]
            pub unsafe fn $variant(&self) -> &$ftype {
                &*(self as *const _ as *const $ftype)
            }
            #[inline]
            pub unsafe fn $variant_mut(&mut self) -> &mut $ftype {
                &mut *(self as *mut _ as *mut $ftype)
            }
        )+}
    );
}

RIDL! {#[uuid(0x56fdf342, 0xfd6d, 0x11d0, 0x95, 0x8a, 0x00, 0x60, 0x97, 0xc9, 0xa0, 0x90)]
interface ITaskbarList(ITaskbarListVtbl): IUnknown(IUnknownVtbl) {
    fn HrInit(
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn AddTab(
        hwnd: i32,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn DeleteTab(
        hwnd: i32,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn ActivateTab(
        hwnd: i32,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn SetActivateAlt(
        hwnd: i32,
    ) -> HRESULT,
}}

RIDL! {#[uuid(0x00000000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x46)]
interface IUnknown(IUnknownVtbl) {
    fn QueryInterface(
        riid: *const GUID,
        ppvObject: *mut *mut c_void,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn AddRef(
    ) -> u32,
    fn Release(
    ) -> u32,
}}

pub type GUID = __MIDL___MIDL_itf_TaskbarLib_0006_0001_0001;

STRUCT! {struct __MIDL___MIDL_itf_TaskbarLib_0006_0001_0001 {
    Data1: u32,
    Data2: u16,
    Data3: u16,
    Data4: [u8; 8],
}}

RIDL! {#[uuid(0x602d4995, 0xb13a, 0x429b, 0xa6, 0x6e, 0x19, 0x35, 0xe4, 0x4f, 0x43, 0x17)]
interface ITaskbarList2(ITaskbarList2Vtbl): ITaskbarList(ITaskbarListVtbl) {
    fn MarkFullscreenWindow(
        hwnd: i32,
        fFullscreen: i32,
    ) -> HRESULT,
}}

STRUCT! {struct tagTHUMBBUTTON {
    dwMask: u32,
    iId: UINT,
    iBitmap: UINT,
    hIcon: LPUNKNOWN,
    szTip: [u16; 260],
    dwFlags: u32,
}}

RIDL! {#[uuid(0xea1afb91, 0x9e28, 0x4b86, 0x90, 0xe9, 0x9e, 0x9f, 0x8a, 0x5e, 0xef, 0xaf)]
interface ITaskbarList3(ITaskbarList3Vtbl): ITaskbarList2(ITaskbarList2Vtbl) {
    fn SetProgressValue(
        hwnd: i32,
        ullCompleted: u64,
        ullTotal: u64,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn SetProgressState(
        hwnd: i32,
        tbpFlags: TBPFLAG,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn RegisterTab(
        hwndTab: i32,
        hwndMDI: wireHWND,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn UnregisterTab(
        hwndTab: i32,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn SetTabOrder(
        hwndTab: i32,
        hwndInsertBefore: i32,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn SetTabActive(
        hwndTab: i32,
        hwndMDI: i32,
        tbatFlags: TBATFLAG,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn ThumbBarAddButtons(
        hwnd: i32,
        cButtons: UINT,
        pButton: *const tagTHUMBBUTTON,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn ThumbBarUpdateButtons(
        hwnd: i32,
        cButtons: UINT,
        pButton: *const tagTHUMBBUTTON,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn ThumbBarSetImageList(
        hwnd: i32,
        himl: LPUNKNOWN,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn SetOverlayIcon(
        hwnd: i32,
        hIcon: LPUNKNOWN,
        pszDescription: LPCWSTR,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn SetThumbnailTooltip(
        hwnd: i32,
        pszTip: LPCWSTR,
    ) -> HRESULT,
    fn SetThumbnailClip(
        hwnd: i32,
        prcClip: *const tagRECT,
    ) -> HRESULT,
}}

ENUM! {enum TBPFLAG {
    TBPF_NOPROGRESS = 0,
    TBPF_INDETERMINATE = 1,
    TBPF_NORMAL = 2,
    TBPF_ERROR = 4,
    TBPF_PAUSED = 8,
}}

pub type wireHWND = *mut _RemotableHandle;

STRUCT! {struct _RemotableHandle {
    fContext: i32,
    u: __MIDL_IWinTypes_0009,
}}

UNION! {union __MIDL_IWinTypes_0009 {
    [u32; 1],
    hInproc hInproc_mut: i32,
    hRemote hRemote_mut: i32,
}}

ENUM! {enum TBATFLAG {
    TBATF_USEMDITHUMBNAIL = 1,
    TBATF_USEMDILIVEPREVIEW = 2,
}}

STRUCT! {struct tagRECT {
    left: i32,
    top: i32,
    right: i32,
    bottom: i32,
}}

// Implements ITaskbarList3
RIDL! {#[uuid(0x56fdf344, 0xfd6d, 0x11d0, 0x95, 0x8a, 0x00, 0x60, 0x97, 0xc9, 0xa0, 0x90)]
class TaskbarList; }
```

And finally an example how to use it:

```
mod TaskBarLib;

use fltk::{button::*, window::*};

fn main() {
    let mut wnd = Window::default()
        .with_size(600, 228)
        .center_screen()
        .with_label("Example");
    wnd.end();
    wnd.show();

    unsafe {
        let hr = winapi::um::objbase::CoInitialize(std::ptr::null_mut());
        assert!(winapi::shared::winerror::SUCCEEDED(hr));

        let mut taskbar: *mut winapi::ctypes::c_void = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let hr = winapi::um::combaseapi::CoCreateInstance(
            &<TaskBarLib::TaskbarList as winapi::Class>::uuidof(),
            std::ptr::null_mut(),
            winapi::um::combaseapi::CLSCTX_ALL,
            &<TaskBarLib::ITaskbarList3 as winapi::Interface>::uuidof(),
            &mut taskbar,
        );
        let taskbar = &*(taskbar as *mut TaskBarLib::ITaskbarList3);
        taskbar.HrInit();
        let hWnd: i32 = wnd.raw_handle() as i32;
        taskbar.SetProgressState(hWnd, TaskBarLib::TBPF_NORMAL);
        for i in 1..100 {
            taskbar.SetProgressValue(hWnd, i, 100);
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(10));
        }
        assert!(winapi::shared::winerror::SUCCEEDED(hr));
    }
}
```